# Estimating Delay in WiFi Using Android

Tags: android, wifi, delay

I have a simple and clear question: Is it possible to send a set of data packets, one packet at a time after the acknowledgement signal from the access point is received using an Android device? The type of signal is not important just the total time passed into the process( within a resolution of ns or us suits my application) is important for me and I don't know a thing about Android, but if such a task can be pulled off in Android, I will learn Android.
Thanks

Comment: In fact does anyone know is there even an acknowledgement signal issued by the access point? What is the signal that should be sent to receive the ack. signal in return?

Answer (score 0):

You can send a System.nanoTime() value to the other device and then substract...the thing is if the 2 devices dont have exactly the same hour, this value will not be real... Anyways, you can sync. both devices sending a "test package" from a fixed distance, sou you can measure the difference according to the test package.

Comment: Why not merge the two ideas? Send `System.nanoTime()` a few times, get some estimates by subtracting pairs (like `d1 = t2 - t1; d2 = t3 - t2; ...`), and combine them by averaging.

Comment: You know what? My real intention is that this time delays should be location dependent and I want to obtain that through the limited speed of light and by sending multiple packets to emphasize that delay.

Comment: And I essentially want the other device to be an accessPoint not an Android device.